# set palette color to blue in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to get a `contour` map using `gnuplot` using `pm3d` and `view map`
while everything else is fine, I cannot convert it to the colorscheme I want.

The present picture, using default colour scheme is attached.[image]

But, it will be great if I can have it in Blues's sheds, from Dark Blue to lighter.
I was trying to follow instruction given [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3dcolors.html), but failed. 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the highly requested but criticized (see links below) [Matlab Jet colormap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI8aA.png), just do:

```
f(x)=1.5-4*abs(x)
set palette model RGB
set palette functions f(gray-0.75),f(gray-0.5),f(gray-0.25)
```

Which, I think, is better than the usual way:

```
set palette defined ( 0 '#000090',\
                      1 '#000fff',\
                      2 '#0090ff',\
                      3 '#0fffee',\
                      4 '#90ff70',\
                      5 '#ffee00',\
                      6 '#ff7000',\
                      7 '#ee0000',\
                      8 '#7f0000')
```

for more information, see the [manpage for palette](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-544)

---

- [The 'jet' colormap must die! <sub><sup>(Wayback Machine)</sup></sub>](https://web.archive.org/web/20141031200806/http://cresspahl.blogspot.com/2012/03/expanded-control-of-octaves-colormap.html)
- [The ‘jet’ colormap, the default colormap in MATLAB, is a perceptual disaster <sub><sup>(Wayback Machine)</sup></sub>](https://web.archive.org/web/20141009075838/http://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/lets-talk-colormaps/)
- [Rainbow Color Map (Still) Considered Harmful <sub><sup>(Wayback Machine, pdf)</sup></sub>](https://web.archive.org/web/20141029123914/http://www.jwave.vt.edu/%7Erkriz/Projects/create_color_table/color_07.pdf)

Comment: Every single link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

See the gnuplot documentation about `set palette`:

```
set palette defined (0 'dark-blue', 1 'light-blue')
test palette
```

or

```
set palette defined (0 '#0000bb', 1 '#8888ff')
```