# GNUPLOT - Setting individual points to RGB colors (scaling)

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I am currently in a project for which I have columns for X and Y values, and a third column representing a third value that I would like visually displayed as a scaling colour.

I have seen people set a colour based on a value for standard colours, however, I want it to scale from RED -> BLUE, with those two colours at the opposite ends of the spectrum.

255,0,0 -> ... 200,0,55 ... -> 55,0,200 -> ... 0,0,255

With 255 possible values, it does not seem efficient to define each.

Therefore, I was wondering if there were a simpler way I could achieve such a goal?

Kind regards.

Comment: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html (too lazy to answer, but that should do what you want)

Comment: Look for `set palette` here on SO, e.g. [set palette color to blue in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20286461/2604213).

Answer (score 0):

There are two approached:

1. You can explicitly set a color for each point of your data by writing

   ```
   plot "data.csv" using 1:2:3 with points linecolor rgb variable
   ```

   The third parameter is a 24 bit color value, i.e.

   ```
   red*256*256 + green*256 + blue
   ```
2. Use a palette and just write

   ```
   plot "data.csv" using 1:2:3 with points palette
   ```

   Have a look at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/pm3dcolors.html for samples of different palettes.

   If you want to set your own colors for the palette, it is done like this:

   ```
   set palette defined (0 0 0 0, 1 0 0 1, 3 0 1 0, 4 1 0 0, 10 1 1 1)
   ```

   The groups of numbers define one color each. The last three numbers are RGB values 0...1, the first is something like a position of the color within the palette. The first color is 0 0 0 (black), then comes blue, green, red, white. About the position: The palette begins with black and ends with white. the colors red, green and blue are at 1/10, 2/10 and 3/10 of the palette range, i.e. the red->white grade is stretched.